# Views query alter or condition not works

Tags: views

Want add some or conditions in view queries. I tried two solutions but it not working. What I do wrong?

```
function up_coaching_custom_views_query_alter(&$view, &$query) {
  $search_string = empty($_GET['filter']) ? '' : '%' . db_like($_GET['filter']) . '%';
  if ($view->name != 'users' || empty($search_string)) {
    return;
  }

  // First way
  $condition = db_or()
      ->condition('users.mail', $search_string, 'LIKE')
      ->condition('field_data_field_company.field_company_value', $search_string, 'LIKE')
      ->condition('field_data_field_user_name.field_user_name_value', $search_string, 'LIKE')
      ->condition('field_data_field_title.field_title_value', $search_string, 'LIKE');
  $query->add_where(2, $condition);

  // Second way
  $query->where[2] = array(
    'args' => array(),
    'type' => 'OR',
    'conditions' => array(
      array(
        'field' => 'users.mail',
        'value' => $search_string,
        'operator' => 'LIKE',
      ),
      array(
        'field' => 'field_data_field_company.field_company_value',
        'value' => $search_string,
        'operator' => 'LIKE',
      ),
      array(
        'field' => 'field_data_field_user_name.field_user_name_value',
        'value' => $search_string,
        'operator' => 'LIKE',
      ),
      array(
        'field' => 'field_data_field_title.field_title_value',
        'value' => $search_string,
        'operator' => 'LIKE',
      ),
    ),
  );
  $query->set_where_group('AND', 2);
  dpm($query);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, both solutions are work. The problem is in query fields that not exist because need add field tables. I didn't unserstand this because of this:

```
    catch (Exception $e) {
        $view->result = array();
        if (!empty($view->live_preview)) {
          drupal_set_message($e->getMessage(), 'error');
        }
        else {
          vpr('Exception in @human_name[@view_name]: @message', array('@human_name' => $view->human_name, '@view_name' => $view->name, '@message' => $e->getMessage()));
        }
      }
```

Views didn't show me error.